# iBeacon / Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE devices) - maximum number of beacons

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I would like to track a large number of beacons (~500) at once within a 50-100 m radius via an app on an iPhone (5s). I've had a look at the spec and online and I can't see if there is any limit on the number of beacons you can track at once using BLE. Does anyone know if there is limitation on the number of beacons you can track exists or if an iPhone 5s would be up to the task of tracking that many beacons?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You used the word track, but iOS has two different methods: monitoring and ranging.

You can set a maximum of 20 regions to monitor. (Found in documentation for the startMonitoringForRegion: method.) Region limits mostly come into play if your app is in the background. The OS will alert your app when you enter or leave a region that you're monitoring (give or take a few minutes). The OS will even launch your app just to let it know what happened (although only for a short time).

The other method is ranging, which is to find all the beacons within the Bluetooth range of the device (typically around 100 feet give or take). If your beacons are spread out over 100 miles, then you probably won't run into any practical limit here. I have not found any documentation for this, and I have only four beacons that I'm testing with, and four at a time works.

Here's one way to handle your situation. Make all your 500 beacons use the same UUID, and make a beacon region using initWithProximityUUID:identifier: method. (Identifier is just for you -- it doesn't affect anything). Starting monitoring for that beacon region. That way, your app will be notified whenever one of your 500 beacons are found (give or take a few minutes). Once notified, you can use startRangingBeaconsInRegion: to find all the beacons around that area, then use the major and minor values to figure out which beacons the user is near.

Comment: Bear in mind, though, that when your app receives an iBeacon notification while in the background, your app only receives a limited amount of time to take action (most likely in the order of seconds). Depending on what action you wish to take, perhaps prompting the user (with a UILocalNotification) to open the app and then start the ranging when the app is open might be the right solution. An example can be found [here](https://www.cocoanetics.com/2013/11/can-you-smell-the-ibeacon).

Comment: What r the limitations Bluetooth should on, GPS?

Answer (score 5):

I'll add to Tim Tisdall's answer, which sets out the right framework. I can't speak to the specific capabilities of the iPhone 5s, or iOS in general, but I don't see any reason why it wouldn't return every ADV_IND packet (i.e. beacon transmission) that it receives.

The question is, will the 500 beacons be able to transmit their ADV_IND packets without collisions?

It takes about 0.128ms to transmit an ADV_IND packet. The time between advertising transmissions is configurable between 20ms and 10240ms (at intervals of 0.625ms), so the probability of collisions depends on the configuration of the beacons.

Based on the Poisson distribution, the probability of a collision for any given ADV_IND packet is 1-exp(-2*N*(0.128/AI)), where N is the number of beacons within range, AI is the time in milliseconds of the advertising interval (assuming all the beacons are configured the same), and the 0.128 is the time in milliseconds it takes to send the ADV_IND packet. (See http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~jgao/CSE590-fall09/aloha-analysis.pdf if you want an explanation.)

For 500 beacons with the maximum advertising interval of about 10 seconds, there will be a collision about once every 81 packets (or about 6 out of 500). If you're willing to wait for a couple intervals (i.e. 30 seconds), there's a good chance you'll be able to receive all 500 ADV_IND packets.

On the other hand, if the advertising interval is smaller, say 500ms, you'll have a collision about 23% of the time (or 113 out of 500). You'd have to wait for several more intervals to improve the probability that you'd see the broadcasts from all the beacons.

The other way to look at it is that the more beacons you have, the longer you have to wait to make sure you receive all their packets. (The math to calculate the delay to receive the packets with a certain probability from the number of beacons and the advertising interval is too much for me today.)

One caveat: if you want to connect to these beacons, as opposed to just receiving the ADV_IND packet, that requires an exchange of two more packets on the advertising channels, and the probability of a collision in the advertising channels goes up a bit.

Answer (score 4):

If I am reading your question right, you want to put all 500 iBeacons within 100 meters of each other, meaning their transmissions will overlap.  You will probably run into radio congestion problems long before you run into any limitations of iOS7 or your phone.

I have successfully tested 20 iBeacons in close proximity without problems, but 500 iBeacons is an extreme density.  [this discussion](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21991/how-many-active-bluetooth-devices-can-i-reliably-detect-in-a-single-space) on the hardware issue suggests you may run into trouble.

At a minimum, the collisions of the transmissions of 500 iBEacons will make it take longer for your iOS device to see each iBeacon.  Normally, iOS7 provides a ranging update once per second for each iOS device, but you may find  that you get updates much less often.  It all depends on your application whether or not less frequent updates are acceptable.

Even if delays are acceptable, I would absolutely test this before counting on it working at all.  Unfortunately, that means getting your hands on lots of iBeacons.

Answer (score 3):

I don't agree. It is true that ble beacons only transmit advertising data, but the transmission of such data last about 3ms (considering three advertising channels). 
Having 500 beacons, WITHOUT considering any collision, the scanner will takes 1.5s to see them all.
But, if all beacons are configured in same way (same advertising interval) it is inevitable to have collisions which lead to have undiscovered beacons. Even if the advertising interval is different between beacons collisions occur. To avoid collision probability one should use longer advertising interval, but this lead to longer discovery latency.
This reasoning is very raw, it doesn't take care of many effects, but is just an order of magnitude calculation.

By the way, the question is not easy, there are many parameters which play role, some are known some are unknown. But I'm working with ble since one year about and, to me, 500 is a huge number and there is the possibility that you don't see the majority of nodes because of collisions.

Comment: I've just write a matlab script that estimate the number of collisions. It suppose the use of ble, therefore using the three adv channels and the duration of tx phase is 466us, no other type of interference is supposed (wi-fi, zigbee, other bluetooth devices).

Comment: Using 1 sec of advertise and 500 nodes, on the average I have 186 nodes that have conflicts and may not be discovered within 1 sec.Of course if the discovery goes on, during the next second of discovery there will be again 186 nodes that are not discoverable (some will be the same, some not),on the next second there will be other 186 and so on.

Comment: This is a very interesting response, and I'd like to learn a bit more about your analysis on conflict estimate modeling for BLE.  Are you willing to publish a gist or the source for your analysis?

Comment: Honestly no, but the analysis is pretty simple. It take one advertise interval (i.e. the interval at which the advertise packets are sent) and randomly disperses the transmission slots of each node over that interval. Any packet that overlaps with any other will be corrupted. You just need to repeat this randomization many times and calculate the average

Comment: @DavideGiovanelli Can I use your phrase `the transmission of such data lasts about 3ms` to give an answer **333** to the question `theoretically, what is the maximum number of advertisements that could be heard by a given listening beacon in a second? `

Answer (score 1):

I was doing some research into iBeacon's because of this question  (I had no idea what it was about).

It seems that on the "beacon" side of things all that happens is general advertising packets are sent out.  It's similar to how a device advertises that you can connect to it.  However, you don't actually connect to iBeacon's, it just reads those advertising packets.  There's no built-in limitation on how many advertising packets a device can receive.

So, it wouldn't surprise me if 500 iBeacon's would run with no issues.  The advertising packets are small and are spaced out (time wise, they are repeated every X ms).  There's no communication going from the phone to the iBeacon, the phone is simply receiving the packets it hears.  If there's interference on one packet it'll likely manage to get the next one.